# image_view stereo_view don't show image or disparity (ROS Kinetic)

Tags: stereo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Kinetic Kame on Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 320x240 gray-scale cameras with camera_info generated by running camera_calibration.

I have the following topics

```
/camera/front/left/image_raw
/camera/front/right/image_raw
/camera/front/left/camera_info
/camera/front/right/camera_info
```

I then generate the disparty map using

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=/camera/front rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc
```

This generates a bunch of topics

```
/camera/front/disparity
/camera/front/left/image_color
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressed
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_color/theora
/camera/front/left/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_mono
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressed
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressedDepth
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_mono/theora
/camera/front/left/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressed
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect/theora
/camera/front/left/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressed
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/theora
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/points2
/camera/front/right/image_color
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressed
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_color/theora
/camera/front/right/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_mono
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressed
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressedDepth
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_mono/theora
/camera/front/right/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressed
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect/theora
/camera/front/right/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressed
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/theora
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_updates
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_descriptions
/camera/front/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_updates
```

I can view the generated rect images for both left and right topics using image_view, but I can't seem to view the disparity topic. When I try and run stereo_view, things just freeze.

```
rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=/camera/front image:=image_rect
```

I'm definitely getting something in the /guidance/front/disparity since rostopic echo splits out a huge array of numbers. Is there another method to view the disparity image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236600/image_view-stereo_view-don%27t-show-image-or-disparity-(ros-kinetic)/) by [uwleahcim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26636/uwleahcim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I tried running my code on a machine with ROS Inidigo and Ubuntu 14.04, and I had no issue displaying the displarity image with image_view stereo_view.  Thus, I'm thinking this might be an issue with either ROS Kinetic Kame.

---

Originally posted by [uwleahcim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26636/uwleahcim/) with karma: 101 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glagla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27526/glagla/) on 2016-07-21**:
Dis you manage to resolve this?

**Comment by [uwleahcim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26636/uwleahcim/) on 2016-07-21**:
I haven't tried displaying the disparity topic with image_view stereo_view. I did convert the disparity topics into depth map using camera_info from the right camera (it has the baseline in the projection matrix). From there I was able to display the depth map via rqt_image_view.

**Comment by [apetersen](https://answers.ros.org/users/27654/apetersen/) on 2016-08-02**:
Could you please post the steps to convert the disparity topic into a depth map by using camera_info from the right camera.  Not sure I follow what you did there and I would like to repeat

**Comment by [uwleahcim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26636/uwleahcim/) on 2016-08-02**:
the disparity image generate by stereo_image_proc is a floating point image following the ROS guidelines. Thus it is very simple and straight forward to convert it into a depth map.  This math is simply just

```
depth = baseline * focallength / disparity
```

(don't have space to post full code).

**Comment by [glagla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27526/glagla/) on 2016-08-03**:
Could you send me the code you tried by mail? @ svendxs@gmail.com please?